# Is the appPaused event working properly for me? I am getting some weird behavior with my clean-up code on iOS

Tags: trigger.io

I have been dealing with this issue for weeks and am unsure if it is my code's fault, forge's appPaused event not triggering quickly enough, or Trigger.io's documentation not being nearly clear enough about just how little time iOS gives us to execute clean-up code.

According to the documentation regarding the appPaused event:

- iOS: A short amount of time is given for execution, it is generally best to assume that callbacks and timers may not fire until the app is resumed.

My application deals with websockets and ideally I am able to send a close event to my server when a user minimizes my app, or the phone is locked. Currently, all of my clean-up code runs perfectly on Android, but on iOS, my clean-up code doesn't run until the app is resumed. The strange part is *sometimes* (maybe 1 out of 20 times) the iOS clean-up is correctly run right after the appPaused event is fired.

To test this I have done two things:

1. I make the very first thing to run after the appPaused event is fired is a message to my websocket server saying "the app is paused". 95% of the time, this message is not actually sent until the app is resumed, but the other 5% of the time my websocket server receives it right after I pause the app.
2. I then made it so the first thing to run after the appPaused event is fired is a line that stores Date.now() in a global variable. I then then store Date.now() in another global variable when the app is resumed, and find the difference between them. It gets interesting because around 50% of the time the Date.now() line is correctly fired right after the appPaused event is called, but the other half of the time the 2 Date.now() calls are only milliseconds a part, proving that the clean-up code was not run until the app resumed.

So, can I really only expect to *sometimes* have enough time after appPaused is fired to even store Date.now() in a variable? Is this what everyone else is experiencing when running their Trigger.io applications on iOS? Let me know if anyone could use more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, appPaused is not guaranteed to fire on iOS. Note, that it may only fire when the app is resumed. 
Any code you want to run on going into the background will probably not run. See the trigger io docs [on events](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/core/event.html). The note on iOS needs careful reading.

That said I have a similar app to yourself dealing in websockets. What i've found is that I can leave the socket open, iOS automatically kills the socket when it suspends the app (Sometime after the paused event is received which corresponds to the ios background state). The server receives the close event and you can of course attach to that event to set any state or cleanup resources. Android requires a manual shutdown of the socket, but appPaused works in a guaranteed way when the app is put into the background.